# How do I report a bug if I have no internet or USB or mouse on my machine?

Tags: bug-reporting

The previous question I posted was closed since I was advised that it was a bug, not a help issue.

That problem was that upgrading from (working) 11.10 to 12.04 (unusable) on my lenovo Y560 has left me with no mouse. The mouse arrow stays frozen in the middle of the screen. No USB devices are recognized at all. There is no internet connection.

So, the problem I am having here is that for the life of me I can't figure out how to report this as a bug, since I can't get any bug-report information out of my lenovo. I can run the suggested "ubuntu-bug xorg", but then I'm stuck because there's no internet, and I can't even hand-copy the information in the "Send problem report to developers?" window because I can't use the mouse to open the drop-down entries, or scroll the window.

Meanwhile, I can't get any help on the problem either because the thread has been closed.

Is there a way to report this bug? How?

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely need to file the bug manually from another machine:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

> Alternatively, you can use this (replace PACKAGENAME in the URL with the package name. For example: unity, gnome-shell, etc):
>
> ```
>  http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/PACKAGENAME/+filebug?no-redirect
> ```

So in your case you can click here to file the bug report:

- http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+filebug?no-redirect

And then copy and paste all the information from your question into that report.